# Computing the market outcome of a monopolist that behaves as a price taker

Tags: microeconomics

**Problem**: Consider  a partial equilibrium of a good x and the composite good m. Consumers have a quasi-linear utility function of $u(x)+m$ with $u(x)=-5(x-6)^2$. Furthermore a single producer produces the good x with a cost function $c(x)=5x^2$

---

From that I computed first the consumer's demand, resulting in the following $D(p)=6-\frac{p}{10}$ (by differentiating $u(x)$ like that $\frac{d u(x)}{dx}$)

Next I computed the supply in a similar manner by differentiating $p*x - c(x)$ resulting in $S(p)=\frac{p}{10}$

---

**Unsolved Problem**: And now I have to compute the market outcome (price, quantity) as ($p^{*}, x^{*}$) when the monopolist does not exercise its market power but behaves as a price taker.

---

And at this point I am not sure how to proceed, as I do not entirely understand what I have to do. Maybe the monopolist price taker is irritating me.

**Approach**: I assumed that I would have to calculate the equilibrium price here by equating supply and demand $S(p)=D(p)$.

Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 2):

> I assumed that I would have to calculate the equilibrium price here by equating supply and demand $S(p)=D(p)$.
>
> Is this the correct approach?

Yes.